# Can I make a preference search?

Tags: search, web, html-helper

so I am starting a website for finding products and I was wondering is it possible to make a search where for example your looking to buy a laptop, and lets say and theres a check box that says "Intel CPU" and "AMD CPU" and once you mark all the specs you want it will give you search results on a specific laptop with those specs! I apologize for my question being so long, But is it possible and how do I approach doing it?

Thanks,

Reese.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You could always have an ajax request sent whenever user clicks the check box and return the list from php (which will connect to the database) and update the list. A lot of websites use this feature.